# Can't run test node on windows

Tags: cardano-node

When I try to run cardano-node on windows, it starts to run fine (*Opened imm db*, *Replaying ledger from genesis*, etc.), so configuration seems fine, but it exits upon trying to create a named pipe:

*CreateSystemdSocketForSnocketPath "\\\\\\\\.\\\\pipe\\\\cardano-node-testnet"*
*DiffusionErrored CreateNamedPipe ('\\\\.\\pipe\\cardano-node-testnet'): does not exist (The specified path is invalid.)*

That UNC-style path above is what I pass as the `--socket-path` param.  In fact, the docs say this is the path is used by the Daedalus Testnet Wallet for Windows, which is running on my machine.  Any proper pipe path should work, but none do.
Suggestions?

**Command (powershell)**

```
./cardano-node run --topology "C:\Program Files\CardanoNode\configuration\testnet-topology.json" --database-path "C:\Program Files\CardanoNode\db" --socket-path "\\\\.\\pipe\\cardano-node-testnet" --host-addr 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --config "C:\Program Files\CardanoNode\configuration\testnet-config.json"
```

**Version**

```
cardano-node 1.29.0 - mingw32-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 4c59442958072657812c6c0bb8e0b4ab85ce1ba2
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, comparing the 2 error messages above gave the answer; I needed to reduce the backslashes passed to `--socket-path` even though the backslashes reported in output as the pipe it tried to create was correct.  So I have to pass `--socket-path "\\.\pipe\cardano-node-testnet"` (apparently the cardano-run doubles them).